# MacOS Screen Saver Start After Field can not be Modified

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, system-settings, mobile-device-management

I have this weirdest problem for MacOS BigSur version 11.1.

I want to change the screen saver "Start after:" parameter to 1 minute. But every time I quit and reopen the System Preferences I see it defaults back to 20 Minutes as in the picture below. (It is like the 1990's jokes of forgetting to "save" before leaving the window.)

I have a suspicion about a zombie profile can be causing this because the computer used to be managed by an MDM profile of a company that I worked for, for a while. But after my project is finished, we removed all profiles. (My suspicion is, still there may be something left that prevents modifying such System Preferences data.)

I don't want to reinstall the whole system only for this silly problem, but still it is extremely annoying considering every time I leave my computer in the wild, when I come back I find it as vulnerable as a gazelle roaming in lions territory.

That's why any comments / suggestions are welcome.

PS: Following command, even though it does not give error, can not modify the value either:

```bash
sudo defaults -currentHost write com.apple.screensaver idleTime -int 60
```

[image]

Comment: Try turning off the Screen Saver, (setting Never,) disable any Hot Corners, uncheck Show with clock, then restart. Does this help? Are the other settings (Hot Corners, Clock) reset as well?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @IconDaemon but unfortunately it did not help. It is reset back to 20 minutes. (There was one Hot Corner, after the change and restart, it is not reset, only the "Start after:" is reset.)

Comment: There is a good writeup here (https://graffino.com/til/UmkCdmEx7v-remove-a-non-removable-mdm-profile-from-macos-without-a-complete-wipe) that might be able to provide you with a better indication as to wether or not you have a rogue profile installed.  I would recommend going to Step 4, but instead of revoking things `rm -rf *` first understand what is there.  do `ls -alh` and post that back to us.

Comment: Hi @TheWellington, first thank you for the comment. I did the whole process, (and took the liberty to continue after the `sudo rm -rf *` step as well, because there were no meaningful data in the files -most of them were 0 length-. After I removed all, regenerated the Settings folder and restarted, the problem is still ongoing.